# Equation involving integrals I saw on a shirt: $\int f(x) = \frac{1}{f'(x)} $

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The equation is
$$
\int f(x) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}
$$
I saw it on a shirt so I thought it is probably a joke, but I couldn't get it. So I tried to solve it. On the first look I thought this is never true. Then I thought of differentiating the whole thing.

$$
f(x) = - \frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)^2}
$$

This is what I got. I don't see any easy solution. This looks like a complicated differential equation.  The only diff. eq. that I know how to solve are the most basic ones that appear in newtonian mechanics.

So, where is the joke if there is one. Or is this equation special in any other way.

Comment: Probably it's meant to be play on the slogan that [integration is the inverse of differentiation](https://www.google.com/search?q=integration+is+the+inverse+of+differentiation).

Comment: I think so too. An esoteric joke.

Comment: so 1/ should represent inverse (awful joke then)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution. Replacing $y=f(x)$ and playing with the derivatives, you should end with $$x''=x' y$$ Then, reduction of order $x'=p$ gives
$$p'=p y \implies p=c_1 e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}$$ One more integration to get
$$x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} c_1 \text{erfi}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+c_2$$ I do not think that we could get the inverse of it.

Comment: +1 hard to inverse ineed Claude

Comment: No? Shouldn't you ve able to go further? $y=\sqrt2\operatorname{erf}(Ax+B)$

Answer (score 3):

We have $f'f=-f''/f'$ so $f^2/2+C=-\ln f'$, i.e. $f'=A\exp -f^2/2$ and $x=A^{-1}\int\exp (f^2/2) df$.